# url not getting file in php

Tags: php, api, slim

I have been following this tutorial [Tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/) and i managed to create the rest api with slim.

here is my .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

just as in the example and then when i go to my index.php

http://localhost/thefaith/v1/user/register

i get a an error

```
    404 Page Not Found

The page you are looking for could not be found. Check the address bar to ensure your URL is spelled correctly. If all else fails, you can visit our home page at the link below.
```

but all my files are well arranged

plus below is my index.php which is in the v1 folder

```
    <?php
include_once '../Includes/account_db_handler.php'; 
require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

// User register
$app->post('/user/register', function() use ($app) {
    // check for required params
    //verifyRequiredParams(array('name', 'email'));

    $response = array();

    // reading post params
    //$name = $app->request->post('name');
    //$email = $app->request->post('email');

    // validating email address
    //validateEmail($email);

    //$db = new AcoountDbHandler();
    //$response = $db->createUser($name, $email);

    $response["message"] = "You are successfully registered";
    // echo json response
    echoRespnse(201, $response);

});


/**
 * Verifying required params posted or not
 */
function verifyRequiredParams($required_fields) {
    $error = false;
    $error_fields = "";
    $request_params = array();
    $request_params = $_REQUEST;
    // Handling PUT request params
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        parse_str($app->request()->getBody(), $request_params);
    }
    foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
        if (!isset($request_params[$field]) || strlen(trim($request_params[$field])) <= 0) {
            $error = true;
            $error_fields .= $field . ', ';
        }
    }

    if ($error) {
        // Required field(s) are missing or empty
        // echo error json and stop the app
        $response = array();
        $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = 'Required field(s) ' . substr($error_fields, 0, -2) . ' is missing or empty';
        echoRespnse(400, $response);
        $app->stop();
    }
}


function echoRespnse($status_code, $response) {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    // Http response code
    $app->status($status_code);

    // setting response content type to json
    $app->contentType('application/json');

    echo json_encode($response);
}

/**
 * Validating email address
 */
function validateEmail($email) {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = 'Email address is not valid';
        echoRespnse(400, $response);
        $app->stop();
    }
}


$app->run();

?>
```

am still new using slim, need some help on how to solve this

Comment: You should focus on htaccess and apache config to solve this, also try `RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]` in your htaccess

Comment: This tutorial and Slim 2 is too old. You should better use Slim 3 with a more up to date [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/odan/d2b889c350aa2ea0ff8e5ca93ce588a2).